# React State Cleared After Button Click?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to keep track of an array of clicked IDs. Whenever I click a new ID (after clicking the first one), it just replaces the old one in the array instead of adding it to the array. I even tried to sanity check by doing the React example of incrementing a "count" state, and that just stays at 1, so clearly I am not sane LOL. Help please!

```
const Example = () => {
  const [downloadedBatches, setDownloadedBatches] = useState<any>([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
      
  const _handleDownload = ({ currentTarget: { dataset: { id } } }: any) => {
    // TODO: Add call
    if (!downloadedBatches.includes(id)) {
      setDownloadedBatches([...downloadedBatches, id])
    }
    console.log(`Downloaded Batch #${id}`)
  }
    
  const _testCount = () => setCount(count + 1);
    
  return (
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={1}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={2}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={3}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_testCount} data-id={3}/>
  )  
}
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the shared code snippet. Is the `Button` component doing something with the passed `onClick` handler like memoizing it when it mounts? Can you share the `Button` component's code? See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issues with the shared code snippet but I suspect the `Button` component is doing something like memoizing the passed `onClick` handler it when it mounts. Regardless of this it's often the case in React you may be working with stale enclosures over a React state value from one render cycle when executing a callback in a later render cycle (*after the state has since updated*). To resolve issues like these you should use [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Functional updates are where you pass a callback function to the state updater function. When the enqueued state update is processed the previous state's value is passed to the callback to be updated from.

Example:

```
const _handleDownload = ({ currentTarget: { dataset: { id } } }: any) => {
  setDownloadedBatches(downloadedBatches => {
    if (!downloadedBatches.includes(id)) {
      // shallow copy previous state and append new id value
      return [...downloadedBatches, id];
    }
    // else just return previous state value, nothing to update
    return downloadedBatches;
  });
}

const _testCount = () => setCount(
  // return previous state value + 1
  count => count + 1
);
```

Code:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [downloadedBatches, setDownloadedBatches] = useState<any>([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
      
  const _handleDownload = ({ currentTarget: { dataset: { id } } }: any) => {
    // TODO: Add call
    setDownloadedBatches(downloadedBatches => {
      if (!downloadedBatches.includes(id)) {
        return [...downloadedBatches, id];
      }
      return downloadedBatches;
    });
    console.log(`Downloaded Batch #${id}`);
  }
    
  const _testCount = () => setCount(count => count + 1);
    
  return (
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={1}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={2}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_handleDownload} data-id={3}/>
    <Button icon={'download'} onClick={_testCount} data-id={3}/>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the state with a Callback.

setDownloadedBatches((prevState) => [...prevState, id])